# Is there something like requireddate for struts2?

Tags: java, forms, date, struts2, validation

I'm trying to validate the birth date of a user. My jsp page is this:

```
<s:form>
...
<s:date name="birthDate" var="formattedVal" />
<s:textfield value="%{#formattedVal}" key="birthDate" />
...
</s:form>
```

My `action-validation.xml` is this:

```
 <field name="birthDate">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message key="birthDate.required" />
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="date">
        <param name="min">01/01/1900</param>
        <param name="max">01/01/9999</param>
        <message />
    </field-validator>
 </field>
```

The problem is that when I put a wrong input in this textfield like: "asñdlkfa", struts2 thinks that the user didn't put anything and then puts the error `birthDate.required`.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that does both validations in a single shot and handles errors the way I *think* you want them handled. At the same time, I'm not sure it's worth writing a custom validator, even though doing so is really easy.

You could do something with a regex validator and handle conversion in the action if it's super-important to you to do it without writing a validator, otherwise I'd probably take a few minutes to write the validator.

Answer (score 0):

### using struts ajax and dojo tags

*
Import taglibs
`<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sd" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>`
*
*
put between `<head>
<sj:head />
<sd:head compressed="false" cache="false" />
</head>`
in body
`<sj:datepicker name="date achat" label="Format (yyyy-MM-dd)"
        displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" maxDate="2012-06-25" />
    <sd:datetimepicker name="date achat" label="Format2 (yyyy-MM-dd)"
        displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" startDate="2012-06-25"></sd:datetimepicker>`specified date as ur requirement
*